# Refactoring methods from ArrayList to HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, refactoring

I need help refactoring my code from using an ArrayList to function, over to a HashMap.

I have made a library where i can store my records. One where i make a new record with tittle, artist and what type of record it is(CD, Vinyl etc). And i made a archive for those.

This method below checks if a record is stored in the archive and returns true if it is or false if it isn't. This one i managed to refactor over to HashMap.

```
public boolean exists(Record record) {
    if(map.containsKey(record.getTitle())) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This method below adds a new record to the archive, uses the previous method i made to return true if a record has been added and false if the record already exists in the arraylist. This one i need help to refactor over to HashMap.

```
public boolean addTo(Record newRecord) { 
    if(exists(newRecord)){
        return false;
    } else {
        map.add(newRecord);
        return true;
    }
```

This below is my attempt to refactor it. Added field variables and constructor for the archive class.

```
public class MediaArchive
{
private String name ;
private String owner ;
private HashMap<String, Plate> map;

public MediaArchive() {
    map = new HashMap<String, Record>();
}

public boolean addTo(Record record) {
    if(exists(record)){
        return false;
    } else {
        map.add(record);
        return true;
    }   
}
}
```

So i need help with refactoring my "addTo" method so it can add records to the HashMap.

Comment: You can use `put` method for the Hash

Comment: So change my .add to .put? I kinda tried that. Might be something else with my code that's not up to par. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: One thing I quickly noticed was your class name `MediaArchive` does not match with constructor name `MedieArkiv `

Comment: @Bunti Yeah i had to rewrite my code to English from Norwegian, might be why.

Comment: What are you going to do when two albums have the same title?  A Java `Map<>` will not allow two entries with identical keys.

Comment: @JimGarrison Actually haven't thought about that yet..

Comment: @DusanBiga So what has happened when you try the `put` method?

Comment: @MaxZoom Was missing `record.getTitle(), record` in the code. It works now, at least it returns true which is what i want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean addTo(Record record) {
    if(exists(record)){
       return false;
    } else {
       map.put(record.getTitle(), record);
       return true;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was pretty simple it seems.